# Drag and drop file into batch file

Tags: batch-file

Okay I have been serching for a answer I understand but getting nowhere. This is my first attemp at a batch file. This is my batch

```
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"
start " " "F:\PUBLIC\shared\Lathe\ScrewMills\ShopAccess\CNC Programs\AEI_Transfer.bat" "%~f1"
If exist *.000 mv *.000 *.456
DEL /Q "*.456" "F:\PUBLIC\shared\Lathe\ScrewMills\ShopAccess\CNC Programs\CURRENT CNC PROGRAM\AEI"
move /y "*.000" "F:\PUBLIC\shared\Lathe\ScrewMills\ShopAccess\CNC Programs\CURRENT CNC PROGRAM\AEI"
pause
exit /b
```

it works if my dropped file is in same folder as batch file but I need to drop files from different folder.
I know this has been covered but Im not getting the paths???

Comment: There are things in the script that are broken in a default Windows install - you need to explain the task itself.

Comment: I am wanting to monitor a folder that holds cnc program. So when they drop a file on my batch file shortcut, it first deletes the last cnc file they ran, then moves new file into folder and another batch file logs it, and I read/write that log file onto my desktop so I always know what part program is being ran.

Comment: This was my original batch file 

@echo off.
If exist *.000 mv *.000 *.456
DEL /Q "*.456" "F:\PUBLIC\shared\Lathe\ScrewMills\ShopAccess\CNC Programs\CURRENT CNC PROGRAM\AEI"
move /y "*.000" "F:\PUBLIC\shared\Lathe\ScrewMills\ShopAccess\CNC Programs\CURRENT CNC PROGRAM\AEI"

This one works if the file I drop is in same folder as Batch file.

Comment: foxidrive, sorry Im not using this forum correctly, way to busy to fix...
This code below works but if i make shortcut to batch, it doesnt work???
Do you know why that is? 
@echo off.
mv *.000 *.456
DEL /Q "*.456" "F:\PUBLIC\shared\Lathe\ScrewMills\ShopAccess\CNC Programs\CURRENT CNC PROGRAM\AEI"
move /y "*.000" "F:\PUBLIC\shared\Lathe\ScrewMills\ShopAccess\CNC Programs\CURRENT CNC PROGRAM\AEI"

Comment: Stop. Putting. Code. In. Comments. It's completely unreadable. Click the _edit_ button under your question and update it that way.

Comment: @JamJoh Your code uses a `mv` command which doesn't exist in Windows.  Is it not looking at a file dropped onto the batch script either - it's not clear what is supposed to be happening or where the files are located.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code which demonstrates how a user can drag and drop a file respectively file name to a command prompt window:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "FileName=""
echo Enter file name with path or drag ^& drop a file on prompt below and press ENTER.
echo(

rem Prompt user for file name. The user can drag and drop a file and
rem press key RETURN or ENTER to enter the file name with path.
set /P "FileName=File name: "

rem Remove all double quotes from file name using a replace with delayed expansion.
set "FileName=!FileName:"=!"

rem Has the user really entered a file name?
if not "!FileName!" == "" (
    echo(
    echo The file name is: !FileName!
    echo(
    pause
)
endlocal
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `if /?`
- `set /?`